# parameter 'probesize' out of range

Tags: opencv, avi

Refer to the following URL.
[OpenCV - Play AVI File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19606988/opencv-play-avi-file)
I found the red message in the console while testing it.
Actually, that code works well on my PC.
But I found the red message in my eclipse console.

[NULL @ 0x83c020] Value 4707126720094797824.000000 for parameter 'probesize' out of range
...
[NULL @ 0x8424c0] Value -4616189618054758400.000000 for parameter 'request_sample_fmt' out of range

Is it normal?
If not how can I figure out their cases.

Comment: I am getting those messages and also many similar ones from OpenCV v2.3.1.  I don't know if they are normal but, so far, they don't seem to interfere with normal operation.

Comment: Thank you. Hope it will not be problem when my program is getting bigger.